# $\mathfrak{g}$-module structure on the tensor algebra $T(g)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

assume that $\mathfrak{g}$ is a finite dimensional Lie algebra. Is rather well-known that its corresponding tensor algebra $T(\mathfrak{g})$ admits a $\mathfrak{g}$-module structure. I have been looking for this $\mathfrak{g}$-module structure, but seems to be different from what I was expecting. For instance I thought that the "natural" action should work (i.e  $g . (u_1  \otimes u_2 \otimes...\otimes u_n)= (g.u_1) \otimes (g. u_2 )\otimes ... \otimes (g. u_n))$. But turns out I think after spending sometime staring it, that isn't quite correct. My books unfortunately doesn't contain any comment about this action (perhaps must be the only one to whom isn't obvious in a first glance :)). Though, I think that a fair action could be something like $g . (u_1  \otimes u_2 \otimes...\otimes u_n) = \sum u_1 \otimes u_2 \otimes ... \otimes (g.u_j) \otimes ... \otimes u_n$, where the leftover terms probably cancel each other out. Can you please give me a reference, or even better explain me if the aforementioned is correct or not? Also is it true that the "natural" action doesn't work in that case?

I forgot to mention that the $\mathfrak{g}$-module structure on $\mathfrak{g}$, is given by the usual *adjoint* action, i.e. $g.u_j=[g,u_j]$.

Thank you!

Comment: There are plenty of $\mathfrak{g}$-module structures on $T(\mathfrak{g})$. It's only interesting if you require something more, so that the module structure is related in some way with the algebra structure on $T(\mathfrak{g})$. It's natural to require that $\mathfrak{g}$ acts by derivations. N.H.'s answer gives the unique action by derivations extending the standard action on $\mathfrak{g}\subset T(\mathfrak{g})$. By the way, it works without finite-dimensional restriction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you refer another such a structure if you know please? Maybe someone else might be interested in.

Comment: You can find one: just think that, if you don't take into account its algebra structure, $T(\mathfrak{g})$ is just an infinite-dimensional vector space (for $\mathfrak{g}\neq 0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the action to be linear, i.e $(\lambda g) \cdot x = \lambda \cdot (g \cdot x)$ for all $\lambda \in k$. With your definition, $(\lambda g) \cdot x = \lambda^n g \cdot x$.

The action of $\mathfrak g$ on $T(\mathfrak g)$ is usually defined on $2$-tensor by $g. (u \otimes v) = g.u \otimes v + u \otimes gv$ which is equivalent to what you wrote.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @N.H. really helped me out a lot. So, the problem with the "natural" action (turns out that isn't) isn't just that doesn't fulfil the axiom $[x,y].m=x.(y.m)-y.(x.m)$, but moreover isn't $\mathbb{k}$-linear?

Comment: This is not $k$-linear as you said and we don't have $(g+h) \cdot u = g \cdot u + h \cdot u$. And you want a morphism of $k$-vector space : $\mathfrak g \to End(T(\mathfrak g))$. I don't think it also satisfy the bracket identity. 
By definition the good action satisfy the axiom you wrote : in fact, this is equivalent to the Jacobi identity.